# JBoss HornetQ setup and Spring

Tags: wildfly, hornetq, spring-jms

I have looked at the threads suggested by SO but couldn't pass the JNDI lookup stage with the following configurations.

My HornetQ conf. is this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<messaging-deployment xmlns="urn:jboss:messaging-deployment:1.0">
<hornetq-server>
<connection-factory name="ConnectionFactory">
    <connectors>
        <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
    </connectors>
    <entries>
    <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
    </entries>
    <consumer-window-size>0</consumer-window-size>
    <retry-interval>1000</retry-interval>
    <retry-interval-multiplier>1.5</retry-interval-multiplier>
    <max-retry-interval>60000</max-retry-interval>
    <reconnect-attempts>1000</reconnect-attempts>
</connection-factory>

<!--the queue used by the example-->
<jms-destinations>
<jms-queue name="test4">
    <entry name="jms/queue/test4"/>
    <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/test4"/>
</jms-queue>
</jms-destinations>
</hornetq-server>
```

My Spring conf. file is this.

```
        <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
<property name="jndiName" value="java:/ConnectionFactory" />
<property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
<property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>
<bean id="myBrokerSendDestination" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
      <property name="jndiName">
          <value>jms/queue/test4</value>
      </property>
      <property name="resourceRef"><value>true</value></property>
</bean>
<bean id="myJmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="myBrokerSendDestination" />
</bean>
```

I am unable to understand the JNDI syntax and I have tried many combinations. I get

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jms/queue/test4 -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jms.queue.test4
```

I am deploying my EAR using Arquillian in JBOSS WildFly 9. I don't know if Arquillian has anything to do with this. But I see successful deploy messages but it fails only with this particular error.

Update : I have modified based on https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Messaging+configuration

But it still fails.

Update: The problems seems to be the hornetq-jms.xml. So this question is irrevelant at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need the leading `java:/` in the local JNDI:

```
<queue name="test4">
    <entry name="queue/test4"/>
    <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/test4"/>
</queue>
```

Comment: As I mentioned I tried such combinations with no success.                             Caused by: `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException`: queue/test4 -- service `jboss.naming.context.java.queue.test4`"}}

Answer (score 0):

Check, if you have enabled remote naming:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.4">
     <remote-naming/>
</subsystem>
```